# Ajax won't send to the same url it's from. Is it possible

Tags: php, ajax, url

I'm trying to send my Ajax request to the same url but
It's not working..    If I put the php on another url and send it, it will work.
I'm trying to keep all of my code on 1 page.  Is this possible?

```
********   thispage.php    *******
<?php
    $theData=$_GET["data"];
    if($theData != ""){
        echo $theData;
        exit;
    }
?>

<script>
function SendData(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    var text = 'OK, it is working';
    xmlhttp.open("GET","thispage.php?data="+text,true); //send it to this page.
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<html>
    <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="SendData()"/>
<html>
```

Comment: Is this the code you are using? the `var text // etc` line is obviously wrong.

Comment: Thanks .. I found the error somewhere else in my code. I have edited the code above to be correct. Hope this helps out others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add exit; after echo $theData;

```
if($theData != ""){
    echo $theData;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. I found the error somewhere else in my code. I have edited the code above to be correct. Hope this helps out others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You have the right concept, but the implementation's not quite right.

```
vat text = 'OK, it's working';
```

I'm not sure if that's a typo, but that should, of course, read:

```
var text = 'OK, it's working';
```

The other, more pertinent, issue here is that you're not actually getting the response using Javascript. You need something like this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
         // do something with the response
         alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

What this does is it sets a handler for when the request completes. In your code:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","thispage.php?data="+text,true); //send it to this page.
```

The `true` argument passed to `xmlhttp.open` tells it to make the request *asynchronous* -- in other words, it doesn't wait for the request to finish before continuing Javascript execution. Thus we need to specify an action for the onreadystatechange event, so that once the request completes, we actually do something with the returned data.

Comment: Thanks ..    I found the error somewhere else in my code.    I have edited the code above to be correct.  Hope this helps out others.